# Is there a way to pass a secret into a Task Module?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an html-based Task Module that interacts with my external service via a REST API. I need to secure these API calls, but because the user who triggers the Task Module may be an anonymous participant in the meeting, I can't use graph authentication.
The best I can do is ensure that the API calls come from the TaskModule that was just created and rely on the authentication of the Bot request to identify the user.

I could add a query parameter to the URL used to launch the html-based Task Module, but query parameters are sent in plain text and often logged on servers.
I could limit the life time of the query parameter, similar to the oAuth flow, but unlike oAuth, my flow requires human interaction between the creation of the "code" and the exchange for a "token" so the life time would need to be longer than I am comfortable with.

I compared the values I get in the Bot "invoke" request for the Task Module with the context object I get back from microsoftTeams.getContext() inside the Task Module itself. I don't see anything that would link the Task Module instance to the specific invoke request.

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the "subEntityId" to be able to pass an opaque value for the specific instance of the TaskModule and authenticate the REST API calls with this secret. So far I haven't found anything that works.

Comment: Hi @Norman Stratton -Is your invoking task module from card or Messaging Extension?

Comment: I have two locations. One is an invoke through a message extension. The other is an invoke action on a button in an adaptive card that the bot has posted to meeting chat.

Comment: @NormanStratton- Are you calling any authenticated REST APIs inside Task Module? did you try using sessions to save access token and fetch it while calling REST APIs?

Comment: @NormanStratton - Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: I got distracted by something more urgent and I'm just coming back to this.
I'm looking into using SSO and passing the token as a bearer token to my app server as either authentication, or to exchange for a session token.
I just need to figure out what I get with SSO if the user is a Federated or Anonymous participant in a Teams Meeting.